# Would Wood count as Earth in Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In Avatar, Earth Benders can bend rock and sand, but would it be possible to bend wood and would it count as Earth?

Comment: What makes you think they might? Just curious.

Comment: @Voldemort- Just thought so just because wood does sound like earth when i think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple Answer:** No. Earthbenders cannot bend wood because it lacks a mineral content. The exception to this might be [petrified wood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrified_wood) since it is wood that has been fossilized and now composed completely of stone.

**The Avatar wiki gives us an extended answer and source under [Weaknesses](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Earthbending#Weaknesses):**

**Metal and wood:** An extension of the last weakness, because nearly all earthbenders do not know how to bend processed metals, the bending abilities of an earthbender can be negated by securing them within a metallic barrier, separating them from any contact with the earth. Toph, however, as the inventor of metalbending, is an exception to this. However, even metalbenders cannot bend highly purified metals such as platinum. **Wood cannot be subject to earthbending because it is neither a mineral nor mineral-like.**

Hamilton, Joshua (writer) & Volpe, Giancarlo (director). (November 2, 2007). "The Runaway". Avatar: The Last Airbender. Season 3. Episode 7. Nickelodeon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It just reminded me of another question i'm going to ask.

Comment: Living wood could be bended by water bending...though it's a little bit of a stretch...

Comment: The source you site (or that the Wiki sites, I can't tell without reading Wiki) provides an even more convincing piece of evidence. In the actual episode of The Runaway, Katara and Toph are thrown into a wooden jail. Neither of them seem able to bend their way out until Katara realizes she could bend the water content of sweat and slice through the wooden bars.

Comment: To prove the point of your exception of "petrified wood", in ATLA season 1, rescuing the earthbenders from the metal prison at sea, they used coal to perform earthbending.